# GGplot2 stack barplot visualization

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, visualization

I want to remove the whitespace between the stacked barplot and place it bellow the Alluvial plot. Please refer to desired output.

```
library(ggalluvial)
library(patchwork)
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# Specify a custom color palette and alpha value
color_palette <- c("#003f5c", "#7a5195", "#ef5675", "#ffa600")
alpha_value <- 0.6  # Adjust the alpha value as needed

# Alluvial plot with the custom color palette and alpha
alluvial_plot <- ggplot(data = vaccinations,
                        aes(axis1 = survey, axis2 = response, y = freq)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = response, alpha = alpha_value)) +  # Apply alpha
  geom_stratum() +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum",
            aes(label = after_stat(stratum))) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Survey", "Response"),
                   expand = c(0.15, 0.05)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_palette) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")  # Remove the legend

# Stacked bar plot with background removed and gap reduced
stacked_plot <- ggplot(data = vaccinations, aes(fill = response, y = freq, x = survey)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity", alpha = alpha_value, width = 1, color = "white") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_palette) +
  theme_void()

combined_plot <- ggarrange(alluvial_plot, stacked_plot,
                    labels = c("A", "B"),
                    ncol = 1, nrow = 2)
```

Current output:

[image]

Desired output (style):
[image]

Comment: Are we supposed to know where to get the `vaccinations` data? If not, can you create the question without that dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Looks possible with `patchwork` and removing axis + plot padding. (Or making them uniform between plots, but removing was easier.)

```
(alluvial_plot <- ggplot(as.data.frame(HairEyeColor),
                        aes(y = Freq,
                            axis1 = Hair, axis2 = Eye, axis3 = Sex)) +
  geom_alluvium(aes(fill = Eye),
                width = 1/8, knot.pos = 0, reverse = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(Brown = "#70493D", Hazel = "#E2AC76",
                               Green = "#3F752B", Blue = "#81B0E4")) +
  guides(fill = "none") +
  geom_stratum(alpha = .25, width = 1/8, reverse = FALSE) +
  geom_text(stat = "stratum", aes(label = after_stat(stratum)),
            reverse = FALSE) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = 1:3, labels = c("Hair", "Eye", "Sex"),
                     expand = expansion(c(0,0))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(c(0,0))) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(y = NULL, x = NULL) + 
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "line")))

# Stacked bar plot with background removed and gap reduced
stacked_plot <- ggplot(data = as.data.frame(HairEyeColor), 
                       aes(fill = Eye, y = Freq, x = Eye)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity", 
           alpha = alpha_value, width = 1, color = "white") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = color_palette) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(c(0,0))) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(c(0,0))) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "line"))

alluvial_plot / stacked_plot
```

[image]